# Jolt transformation nested grouping

Tags: jolt

/// I have json input like below

```
    [{
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "Humidity",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "RH",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "BatteryVoltage",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "V",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "Shock",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "G",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "Vibration",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "Hz",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "Humidity",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "%",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "Temperature",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "C",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}, {
    "shipment_id": 2,
    "schd_date": "2019-12-10 18:27:06.0",
    "contract_start_date": "2019-11-25 00:00:00.0",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "company_id": 9,
    "device_id": 6123,
    "parameter_name": "ACCZ",
    "sensor_upper_threshold": "12",
    "sensor_lower_threshold": "10",
    "parameter_unit": "g",
    "route_id": 6642,
    "source_stop_id": 10379,
    "stop_seq_no": 1,
    "route_efctv_from_dt": "2014-10-24 00:00:00.0",
    "route_efctv_to_dt": "2019-12-31 00:00:00.0"
}]
```

// Desired conversion using JOlt is like below :

```
{
"digifleet_id": "",
"shipment_number": "723984223",
"shipment_date": "2019 - 12 - 23",
"contract_number": "",
"customer_id": "",
"device": [{
    "device_id": "738293827472834",
    "sensors": [{
        "type": "temperature",
        "upper_threshold": 12,
        "lower_threshold": 3,
        "uom": "C"
    }]
}],
"route": [{
        "stop_seq_number": 1,
        "stop_id": "",
        "route_efctv_from_dt": null,
        "route_efctv_to_dt": 201912231400
    },
    {
        "stop_seq_number": 2,
        "stop_id": "",
        "route_efctv_from_dt": 201912311923,
        "route_efctv_to_dt": null
    }
]
```

}

Comment: hi I am very new to nifi and json content, trying to convert json to nested grouping

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question, have a look at the formatting aids on top of the editor window and on the right column, and format your question correctly more specifically the code blocks so that they are readable. The preview below the editor updates live so you can check the result of your changes before you publish.

Comment: Can you include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.

Comment: @Adithya Can you add your jolt specification tried?